# Inviting/viewing members to clan - Discord.js and Enmap

Tags: javascript, arrays, database, discord, discord.js

In an earlier post, I asked for help regarding my Clans System that was written using discord.js and quick.db for database. I've decided to do a rewrite using Enmap since using quick.db will be difficult to work with and everything seems to go well from this point.

I am facing an Issue Invite Clan Member and Clan Info Command, What it is doing is that whenever I run the invitemember command to invite someone to my clan, It does add the member successfully.

The way the Member data is stored is weird as it does:
`Example#4861Example#4861` (This will show on Clan Info Command). I am trying to code it to be like in the Clan Info Embed:

***Members | 2/4***

**Owner:** NTM Nathan#0001

**Members:**

RyansHDs#4461

Kazuchi#4861

and so on...

[image]

Current way the data is stored for Members when Invite Command is run 2nd time or more

```
    data.clanmember += `${user.tag}`

    client.clan.set(data.clan, data)
```

Full code: https://haste.natebot.xyz/agajumejoz.js

After user says yes to join clan, they will be added to a clan. It then Results in this (Shown in Clan Info command):

[image]

ClanInfo: https://haste.natebot.xyz/devejirave.js

I've tried other ways but I kept getting `undefined`. Would there be a better solution to fixing this in Enmap? I understand that MongoDB, MySQL is better but I am not really that experienced with them yet.

If you want to understand how the Clans are being created, its done with createclan command. The Data Structure:

```
  let data = client.clan.get(`${name}`)

let newData = {
    clan: name,
    clanid: Math.floor(Math.random() * 200000),
    clanowner: message.author.tag,
    clanowneravatar: message.author.displayAvatarURL,
    clanownerid: message.author.id,
    clandate: date,
   clanmember: [""]
    }

    client.clanmember.set(`${name}`, {
      clanmember: [" \n"]
    })
    client.clan.set(name, newData)
```

Answer (score -1):

try to use mysql and define it like "result" then in members do result[0].members, result[1].members etc